# Importing data from multiple related tables in mySQL to SQLite3 or postgreSQL

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, sqlite

I'm updating from an ancient language to Django. I want to keep the data from the old project into the new.

But old project is mySQL. And I'm currently using SQLite3 in dev mode. But read that postgreSQL is most capable. So first question is: Is it better to set up postgreSQL while in development. Or is it an easy transition to postgreSQL from SQLite3?

And for the data in the old project. I am bumping up the table structure from the old mySQL structure. Since it got many relation db's. And this is handled internally with foreignkey and manytomany in SQLite3 (same in postgreSQL I guess).

So I'm thinking about how to transfer the data. It's not really much data. Maybe 3-5.000 rows.

Problem is that I don't want to have same table structure. So a import would be a terrible idea. I want to have the sweet functionality provided by SQLite3/postgreSQL.

One idea I had was to join all the data and create a nested json for each post. And then define into what table so the relations are kept.

But this is just my guessing. So I'm asking you if there is a proper way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

better create the postgres database. write down the python script which take the data from the mysql database and import in postgres database.